# How to make a line chart using JQPLOT from a txt file with arranged data

Tags: jqplot

I'm a beginner! I have a txt file with some data arranged in column and I want to  display each column with a different line in a line chart using JQPLOT. Is there any way to do that without convert the txt file in a json file or an xml file?

Here an example of my txt file:

```
description line 1   <-- I'm not interested in this line
description line 2   <-- I'm not interested in this line
1.22 2.23 3.43 4.45  <-- The 4 columns are separed by a space
1.20 2.10 4.49 5.12
1.10 3.02 3.98 4.78
1.22 2.23 3.43 4.45
1.20 2.10 4.49 5.12
1.10 3.02 3.98 4.78 `
```

Sorry for my bad english!
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to convert the data to JSON or XML.  You can make an AJAX request for the txt file and then parse it into the format jqplot expects (none of the code below is tested, but should get you started):

```
$.ajax({url:"/path/to/Text.txt",
  success:function(result){
    var fileLines = result.split("\n") //result is the file, split on the lines
    var jqplotData = [];
    for (var i = 2; i < fileLines.length(); i++) // skip first two lines
    {
       var aLine = fileLins[i].split(" ");
       var aSeries = [];
       for (var j = 0; j < aLine.length(); j++)
       {
          aSeries.push(parseFloat(aLine[j])); // build array for each series 
       }
       jqplotData.push(aSeries); // add series to larger data array
    }

    // now call jqplot with your data...
    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartDiv', jqplotData, {});
  }
});
```